# How to use tastypie for showing contents of model based on client_id in oauth 2.0?

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

I have a problem where I want to filter model resourse based on a field and show that particular queryset to the requesting client_id.

I am using tastypie v0.10.0 with django 1.6.5 and swagger UI for documentation.

In Example model I have stored information related to all clients and want to show the data belongs to the particular client based on client id. I have filters fields in Example model based on which I can create queryset for particular client.

```
class Resource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Example.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'example'
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get',]
        authentication = OAuth20Authentication()
```

Please suggest me the best way to implement the above scenario. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came out with.

```
import provider.oauth2
from provider.oauth2.models import AccessToken


class Resource(ModelResource):
    # 
    class Meta:
        queryset = Example.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'example'
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get',]
        always_return_data = True
        authentication = OAuth20Authentication()

        key = bundle.request.GET.get('oauth_consumer_key')
        if not key:
            key = bundle.request.POST.get('oauth_consumer_key')
        if not key:
            auth_header_value = bundle.request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
            if auth_header_value:
               key = auth_header_value.split(' ')[1]

        token = verify_access_token(key)
        >>>>> token.user this contains username
        >>>> come out with the proper conditions through which you can create queryset
        queryset = Example.objects.filter(field=condition)
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

I think of two possibilities, how to filter you resources based on client_id. I suppose client_id is one field of your model:

Or you can use tastypie filtering:

```
class Resource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Example.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'example'
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get',]
        authentication = OAuth20Authentication()
        filtering = {
            'client_id': 'exact',
        }
```

This time, you should pass filtering parameter by GET method, something like:

```
http://website.com/api/?client_id=5
```

Or you can write your own obj_get_list method::

```
class Resource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Example.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'example'
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get',]
        authentication = OAuth20Authentication()

    def obj_get_list(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        queryset = Message.objects.filter(client_id = bundle.request.GET['client_id'])
        return queryset
```

Comment: Thanks for response, But I dont have client_id into my model. provider.oauth2 is having that. I just get AccessToken in header of the HTTP request through with I can get the client ID. Can you tell me from where can I get the Header Info ?

Comment: i think you can access HTTP headers via bundle.request.META['AccesToken?']

Comment: here is example https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

Comment: I got the Header through bundle.request.META.get("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION")

But obj_get_list is not working. Its giving me whole data stored in model.

Comment: But its not exactly proper answer for the question I asked for. Using oauth2.